# Is it anti-pattern to call redux-thunk action from a helper function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, anti-patterns, redux-thunk

I have a helper function which is a fetch request builder. It creates object from parameters and invokes fetch request. It then checks result of the request, if server's answer is ok. If server responds with 401, user should be sent to login page with and auth should be cleared, which is done in action.

```
export const fetchBuilder = (method, url, data, token) => {
  const req = {
    method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  };
  if (method === 'POST') {
    req.body = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, req).then(
      (response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            resolve(data);
          } else {
            if (response.code === 401) {
              // here code to clear redux store from old token and send to login
            }
            reject(data);
          }
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        reject(error);
      },
    );
  });
  return promise;
};
```

The question is, is it ok to call the logout action from this helper function. It means I must pass the dispatch into this helper function

```
export const fetchBuilder = (method, url, data, token, dispatch)
```

in order to pass it again into action like this

```
logout()(dispatch);
```

If not, what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Why not just handle the `failure/reject` case in your `thunk/action`?

Comment: That is how I handled initially. But after using my helper function 3-4 times I understood that I am repeating the same code if reject handling, which is basically the same every time.